# Undeclared identifier on pinescript for a backtest strategy

Tags: pine-script-v4

I can't find my error in this code. Could you help me? This is supposed to be a test code for backtesting in pinescript version 4. The Error is "undeclared identifier 'macdval' and 'macdsignalVal' ligne 38 and 38

```
//@version=4

// Paramètres de l'indicateur MACD
fastMA = 12
slowMA = 26
signalMA = 9

// Paramètres de l'indicateur RSI
lengthRSI = 14
overbought = 70
oversold = 30

study("My Script", overlay=true)
macdVal = macd(fastMA, slowMA, signalMA)
macdSignalVal = ema(macdVal, signalMA)
rsiVal = rsi(close, lengthRSI)

// Variables pour stocker les positions d'achat et de vente
buyPrice = 0.0
sellPrice = 0.0

// Vérifier les conditions d'entrée
if crossover(macdVal, macdSignalVal) and rsiVal < oversold
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
else if crossunder(macdVal, macdSignalVal) and rsiVal > overbought
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Vérifier les conditions de sortie
if crossover(macdVal, macdSignalVal) or rsiVal > overbought
    strategy.exit("Long")
else if crossunder(macdVal, macdSignalVal) or rsiVal < oversold
    strategy.exit("Short")

// Afficher les indicateurs sur le graphique
plot(macdVal, color = color.blue, linewidth = 2)
plot(macdSignalVal, color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
plot(rsiVal, color = color.yellow, linewidth = 2)
```

I searched through the code for the error but could not find it

Comment: Are you using chatGPT?.
Due to such poor accuracy [Stackoverflow has banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).
TradingView has also decided [not to provide any QA support for ChatGPT](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/).

Comment: study should be on line 2. macd is missing the source (close). there are various bugs that can be attributed to ChatGPT